# Python logging: charmap can't handle Chinese characters, can't seem to encode as utf-8

Tags: python, logging, utf-8, character-encoding, python-logging

So I have created a Python program which will delete all the public links to files in our company Dropbox. I will occasionally log something that involves a filename, for instance if it finds a publicly shared file while in the file checking process:

```
filepath = file.path_lower
...
dmsg = filepath + " public"
logger.debug(dmsg)
```

This works fine for most filepaths. However, we have some filepaths with Chinese characters in them, and these are causing issues. My logging setup looks like this:

```
import logging
...
    fmt = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s(%(name)s): %(message)s"

    # Dropbox logs a lot of things; set up where they will go
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="dropbox default logging.log",
        encoding='utf-8',
        format=fmt,
        level=logging.DEBUG)
    
    # we want a separate file for the messages we actually care about
    handler = logging.FileHandler("unsharing program.log", encoding="utf-8")
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger("UnsharingProgram")
    
    # Before I added this handler remove code I had some.. issues. Don't touch
    for handler in logger.handlers[:]:
        logger.removeHandler(handler)
    
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

But whenever it gets to a file that contains a Chinese character, I get this error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1086, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 133-135: character maps to <undefined>
Call stack:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 328, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
    await self.process_one()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
    await dispatch(*args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
    reply_content = await reply_content
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
    return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2863, in run_cell
    result = self._run_cell(
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2909, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in run_cell_async
    has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3309, in run_ast_nodes
    if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10272\3176266708.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    runfile('C:/Users/[redacted]/.spyder-py3/dropbox unshare public files in folder.py', wdir='C:/Users/[redacted]/.spyder-py3')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 577, in runfile
    exec_code(file_code, filename, ns_globals, ns_locals,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 465, in exec_code
    exec(compiled, ns_globals, ns_locals)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 378, in <module>
    unshare_public_files(folder_to_unshare)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 89, in unshare_public_files
    find_shared_links_in_folder(folder_path)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 171, in find_shared_links_in_folder
    find_shared_links_in_folder(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 171, in find_shared_links_in_folder
    find_shared_links_in_folder(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 171, in find_shared_links_in_folder
    find_shared_links_in_folder(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 162, in find_shared_links_in_folder
    link_sharing_check(file, links)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\.spyder-py3\dropbox unshare public files in folder.py", line 191, in link_sharing_check
    logger.debug(dmsg)
Message: '[filename with Chinese characters] public'
Arguments: ()
```

For some reason, sometimes this triggers my exceptions that stop the entire code (in the major functions I have try/except blocks that exit the code if triggered) and sometimes it doesn't. I have been going insane trying to figure out how to make it encode using utf-8 instead of charmap - I can live with it when it's just throwing errors and continuing on its merry way, but sometimes it stops the whole thing in its tracks. It's currently running throwing errors without stopping, but I'm not even sure what changed between the last run where it stopped the whole program and this one.

I have tried setting literally everything that can be encoded as utf-8 to do so including things that have nothing to do with the logging. I even tried adding ".encode().decode('utf-8')" to the end of any filepath that was being logged but that didn't work (I didn't really expect it to...)

I am using Python 3.9 through Spyder, which I installed using Anaconda.

Comment: presumably there is a dropbox module that needs to be imported to make the code work ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L Oh, yes, I guess I forgot that. You have to import logging. Added that to the code.

Comment: @D.L No dropbox module is required. The issue is *not* with Dropbox itself, and there aren't actually any dropbox-specific lines of code in the example I provided - it's that the logger doesn't like when there are Chinese characters. the "filepath" is just a string.

Comment: thanks for the update, but the code still does not work because `fmt` is not defined...

Comment: @D.L how about that?